# How to check if a variable is an video tag?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am trying to check if the selected element is an video.

MY html

```
<div class='component'>
    <video><source.../></video>
</div>
```

My js

```
$('.component').on('click', function(){
  var newElement = $(this).children().first();  //I need to keep the children().first() for  
                                                other purpose

  if(newElement.find('video').length){   //this will never be true..
        alert('is video')
   }
})
```

How do I detect if the `newElement` is an `video` tag? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if (newElement.is('video')) {
```

http://api.jquery.com/is/